# Sum two stored procedures and group by publishers

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have stored procedures A and B fetching results from different tables. Both procedures has results with:

- ItemID
- Price
- Quantity
- SUM
- Publisher

Is it possible to SUM both of the stored procedures, and then group by author? Any guides or tips on how i can solve this?

```
DECLARE @OverallResults AS TABLE
(
  identifiers INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    sales_price INT, 
    quantity INT,
    PUBLISHER VARCHAR
)

INSERT INTO @OverallResults (identifiers, sales_price, quantity,PUBLISHER)
EXEC reportItunes

INSERT INTO @OverallResults (identifiers, sales_price, quantity,PUBLISHER)
EXEC reportDDS

SELECT A.Publisher, 
       SUM([sales_price]) AS [TotalPrice], 
       SUM([Quantity] AS [TotalQuantity], 
FROM @OverallResults A
GROUP BY A.Publisher
```

**[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a table variable with that structure and insert the result sets of both SPs in the table variable:

```
DECLARE @OverallResults AS TABLE
(
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  ... Your other columns
)

INSERT INTO @OverallResults ([ItemID], [Price], [Quantity], [SUM], [Publisher])
EXEC StoredProcedure1

INSERT INTO @OverallResults ([ItemID], [Price], [Quantity], [SUM], [Publisher])
EXEC StoredProcedure2

SELECT A.Publisher, 
       SUM([Price]) AS [TotalPrice], 
       SUM([Quantity] AS [TotalQuantity], 
       SUM([Sum]) AS [TotalSum]
FROM @OverallResults A
GROUP BY A.Publisher
```

---

```
DECLARE @OverallResults AS TABLE
(
    identifiers INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    sales_price INT, 
    quantity INT,
    PUBLISHER VARCHAR(128)
)

INSERT INTO @OverallResults (sales_price, quantity,PUBLISHER)
EXEC reportItunes

INSERT INTO @OverallResults (sales_price, quantity,PUBLISHER)
EXEC reportDDS

SELECT A.Publisher, 
       SUM([sales_price]) AS [TotalPrice], 
       SUM([Quantity] AS [TotalQuantity] 
FROM @OverallResults A
GROUP BY A.Publisher
```

Then you can use the table variable to do aggregations.

**Your script, corrected**

1. Removed autoincrement column from insert list
2. Specified a non-default length for the Publisher column
3. Removed extra comma in the last select

Comment: I also want to SUM the [Quantity] and [SUM], can i do that?

Comment: @Lebowski: Updated answer, but it was really not very hard to do.

Comment: Hey i updated my post now, and it is not working.. Can you see whats wrong buddy?

Comment: @Lebowski: Update the question with what you tried and the error. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Lebowski: Check updated answer. You had some syntax errors there.

Comment: Tried it, getting this error: [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: @Lebowski: Not sure what the problem is. I just tested this here with a similar SPs resutset structure and it works fine.